# Angularjs showing time portion from date time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following input which displays datetime

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
<input ng-model="item.time" />
</div>
```

The issue i have is that time is in following format.

```
"2002-11-28T14:00:00Z"
```

I want to just display the time portion. For which I would have to apply filter

```
date: 'hh:mm a'
I tried       
ng-model="labor.start_time | date: 'hh:mm a'"
```

How can I show only time portion in input box showin time only? I can't use span tag as the time a user can change so have to show in input tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above Gaul said, you can use watcher for it.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="currentDate">
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.currentDate = new Date();

    $scope.$watch('currentDate', function(date){
        $scope.currentDate = $filter('date')(date, 'shortTime');
    });
}
```

This is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4108/) with your example.

Comment: I see it is working fine. But I am in ng-repeat and in order for the time to update I have to use in your case like item.currentDate and when i updated with item. it doesnt work. How would I do it inside ng-repeat Thanks

Comment: @J.Davidson, please, can you provide your html template, because I don't fully understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

`item.time` is being overwritten with whatever you type in that input. so when you change the inputs content to a time value only, `item.time` will also only contain the time portion. You'll need a extra variable to hold the time portion and update the datetime value if the time value changes. You can use a $watch for that

```
$scope.$watch('item.time_portion', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // update the hours and minutes of $scope.item.time here
});
```